# Two integrable function such that $\left( \int_1^3 f(x) g(x) dx \right)^2 = \left( \int_1^3 f^2(x) dx \right) \left( \int_1^3 g^2(x) dx \right)$

Tags: integration

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two integrable function, $x \in [1,3]$ satisfying

$$\left( \int_1^3 f(x) g(x) dx \right)^2 = \left( \int_1^3 f^2(x) dx \right) \left( \int_1^3 g^2(x) dx \right)$$

Given that f(1)=2 and g(1)=4

My sir told me that

$$\frac{g(3)}{f(3)}= \frac{g(1)}{f(1)}=2$$

But I could not understand how he has said that ?

Comment: @PiotrBenedysiuk why ?

Comment: You will need to assume that $f(3)$ and $g(3)$ are both nonzero.

Comment: @edm why we have to assume like that

Comment: @user135482 or else you divide by zero.

Comment: @edm I want to know how they got the ratio

Answer (score 7):

[Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) implies that $f$ and $g$ are linearly dependent. That is, there exist two nonzero constants $\lambda$ and $\mu$ such that $\lambda f=\mu g$ almost everywhere. With no further information, little more can be said.

For example, if $f$ and $g$ are continuous we can delete the word "almost". If in addition, if both $f(1)$ and $f(3)$ are nonzero, then
$$\frac{g(3)}{f(3)}=\frac{g(1)}{f(1)}=\frac\lambda\mu$$

Comment: Can we say like this $\frac{g(3)}{f(3)}=\frac{g(2)}{f(2)}=\frac\lambda\mu$. That is instead of 1 we can use any other value

Comment: The two functions are simply assumed to be integrable instead of continuous, so the binary function $\langle f,g\rangle:=\int_{1}^{3}f(x)g(x)dx$ is not an inner product on the space of integrable functions defined on $[1,3]$, and in the strict sense, we can't really use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to show that $f$ and $g$ are linearly dependent. A counterexample is given by two functions $f$ and $g$ that are zero everywhere except $f(1)=2,f(3)=1,g(1)=4,g(3)=1$. This example also shows that the binary function is not an inner product.

Comment: As for the linear dependence almost everywhere, I think you need a proof other than proofs for Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prove that the ratio is $2$. Consider two functions $f$ and $g$ that are zero everywhere except $f(1)=2,f(3)=1,g(1)=4,g(3)=1$. These functions are integrable and satisfy the equality as both sides are zero. But $$\frac{g(3)}{f(3)}=1.$$

Comment: From where do you get f(3) =1 and g(3)=1

Comment: @user135482 They are constructed to be.

Comment: Can you explain it more

Comment: Does it mean my sir is wrong

Comment: @user135482 Do I explain how I come up with the functions or how they satisfy the equality?

I don't know if you have wrote the question exactly as he said, but usually we would need to assume further that $f$ and $g$ are continuous and at least one of $f(3)$ and $g(3)$ is nonzero or else the example as I wrote would be a counterexample.

Comment: If possible could you explain both of them

Comment: Functions with only removable discontinuities and no other types of discontinuities are known to be integrable, and I can easily manipulate the ratio $\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}$ at finitely many $x$ without altering the value of integral. As for the integrals being zero, notice that the points where $f$ and  $g$ are nonzero are too few and the total length of those points is too short to contribute any significant value to the integral.